# PineScript - Quantity for the Last Order

Tags: pine-script

I want to know the quantity of the last closed contract, and if it is negative, the quantity will doubled in the new entry, and if it is positive, it will be the same specified quantity

I tried to do it using strategy.closedtrades.size(strategy.closedtrades)
But orders do not appear on chart ?

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy1", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)
q= 0.1

trade_profit = strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades)
last_trade_size = strategy.closedtrades.size(strategy.closedtrades)


longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long,qty=trade_profit > 0? q : last_trade_size*2)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short,qty=trade_profit > 0? q : last_trade_size*2)
```

Answer (score 0):

While `strategy.closedtrades.size` and `strategy.closedtrades.profit` are zero based, `strategy.closedtrades` returned the total number of trades (not zero based).

Therefor you will need to write:

```
trade_profit = strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
last_trade_size = strategy.closedtrades.size(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
```

The other issue is that if the last closed trade is short, than `last_trade_size*2` will be a negative number which is not allowed in `qty` parameter. It's best if you'll use `math.abs(last_trade_size*2)` for this.

Here is the full code after the changes (I made a small change also to check if there were any closed trades):

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy1", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

q = 1.0

trade_profit = strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades-1)
last_trade_size = strategy.closedtrades.size(strategy.closedtrades-1)


if strategy.closedtrades > 0 and trade_profit > 0
    q := math.abs(last_trade_size * 2)


longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long, qty=q)
    

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))

if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short, qty=q)
```

Here is a list of example trades:

[image]

Comment: I tried it but it shows a blank chart .. without orders

Comment: I edited my answer and added more details. Let me know if it worked

Comment: Thank you so much, you taught me something new for me, especially as I am a beginner in pine script
Note that you have deleted:  qty=trade_profit > 0? q : last_trade_size*2
But when I re-use it, I got an error, the purpose of this is to double the quantity for the last losing order

Comment: It's the same if you write `qty=trade_profit > 0? q : last_trade_size*2` or the way i wrote it with the extra `if` statement. You can delete the extra if statement in my code, and add `qty=trade_profit > 0? q : last_trade_size*2` if you wish. The only thing that you need to keep in mind - you'll get the same error since it's the problem. If the last trade was short, then `last_trade_size` is negetive, and you can't put negative numbers in `qty=` parameter. Use `qty=trade_profit > 0? q : math.abs(last_trade_size*2)` instead